# C++ - vector push_back() not working after fgets()

Tags: c++, vector, codeblocks

I'm working with Code::Blocks with MinGW on Windows 7;

I have this function that works fine:

```
Hueso* getSkel(int cual)
{
    unsigned int cont; //SkelCargados and CantSkel are global vectors
    for (cont =0; cont < SkelCargados.size();cont++) if ( CantSkel[cont] == cual) break; // EDIT: I changed <= with < before SkelCargados.size()
    if (SkelCargados.empty() || cont>SkelCargados.size())
    {
        char linea[LINEA]; //LINEA is a macro. Max value for this string.
        FILE * f = fopen("esqueletos.txt","rt");
        if (f == NULL) return NULL;
        fgets (linea,LINEA,f);

        vector<float> puntos_; // <-- please pay attention in these 4 lines
        puntos_.push_back(2.2);
        puntos_.push_back(2.2);
        puntos_.push_back(2.2);

        while (!feof(f))
        {
            //...
        }
        fclose(f);
    }
    return SkelCargados[CantSkel[cont]];
}
```

And this one, that crashes while trying the 2nd push_back. The (NOT)funny thing is that when I put the vector and its push_back()s before fgets, it behaves normally.

**EDIT:** If I declare the vector as global variable it works fine too.

```
bool CargarMapa()
{
    char linea[LINEA];
    FILE * f = fopen("mapas.txt","rt");
    if (f == NULL) return false;
    fgets (linea,LINEA,f);


    vector<float> puntos_;
    puntos_.push_back(2.2);
    puntos_.push_back(3); //Here it crashes
    puntos_.push_back(4.2);


    while (!feof(f))
    {
        //...
    }
    fclose(f);
    return true;
}
```

This is what happens when it crashes: The debugger throws **"Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault."** and goes to the line marked with a "HERE IT STOPS" comment, in file "new_allocator.h":

```
//(I did not write the following comment)

/*
 @brief  An allocator that uses global new, as per [20.4].
 @ingroup allocators

 This is precisely the allocator defined in the C++ Standard. 
   - all allocation calls operator new
   - all deallocation calls operator delete
*/
template<typename _Tp>
class new_allocator
{
public:
  typedef size_t     size_type;
  typedef ptrdiff_t  difference_type;
  typedef _Tp*       pointer;
  typedef const _Tp* const_pointer;
  typedef _Tp&       reference;
  typedef const _Tp& const_reference;
  typedef _Tp        value_type;

  template<typename _Tp1>
    struct rebind
    { typedef new_allocator<_Tp1> other; };

  new_allocator() throw() { }

  new_allocator(const new_allocator&) throw() { }

  template<typename _Tp1>
    new_allocator(const new_allocator<_Tp1>&) throw() { }

  ~new_allocator() throw() { }

  pointer
  address(reference __x) const { return std::__addressof(__x); }

  const_pointer
  address(const_reference __x) const { return std::__addressof(__x); }

  // NB: __n is permitted to be 0.  The C++ standard says nothing
  // about what the return value is when __n == 0.
  pointer
  allocate(size_type __n, const void* = 0)
  { 
if (__n > this->max_size())
  std::__throw_bad_alloc();

return static_cast<_Tp*>(::operator new(__n * sizeof(_Tp))); //HERE IT STOPS
  }
```

Please, help me. :(

Comment: I guess it's a type issue, try `puntos_.push_back(3.0);`

Comment: @Simon Bang Terkildsen it's not an issue

Comment: @DenisErmolin well glad I didn't put money on it then :)

Comment: @Umagon Try calling `fflush`, after your fgets call.

Comment: @Cthulhu Mmmmm.. Nope, it still crashes. :(

Comment: Then there are more problems that isnt showed to us. Segfault is hard to detect, especially when your havent code to execute. Do you have any heap allocations? Check other containers for bounds etc

Comment: Is there some way to make the error messages more meaningful or some control tool to check memory allocations faster? This error is always haunting me when I do something wrong and it never explains nothing to me, and I spend so much time trying to figure out what happens until I fix it.

Comment: @Umagon That's how C++ is. The only real answer is not to make these mistakes in the first place. Could learn Java instead, it's a much more helpful language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (cont =0; cont<=SkelCargados.size();cont++) if ( CantSkel[cont] == cual) break;
```

is not what you want. You probably wanted to use the comparison operator `<` instead of `<=` in your loop termination condition. As written, if there is one item in that vector, you might end up `break`ing on an index of `1`, which would result in you trying to index to position `1` in the vector which only has one position. (Remember, vectors, arrays, and other similar constructs are zero-indexed, so `[0]` is the first element, `[1]` is the second, etc.)

Most likely the bug lies not in the `push_back` where it actually fails for you, but somewhere else in the code where you corrupted memory (which results in undefined behavior).

Comment: Yeah, that probably slipped. Anyway I made this change, but it still crashes. Oh I forgot another funny thing, I'll edit right away.

Comment: @Umagon: Then that's consistent with what I said. When you have memory corruption, the crash will often be far away from the cause of the crash. Wherever the problem is, it is extremely unlikely for that problem to be in `std::vector::push_back`.

Answer (score 0):

The `<=` doesn't look right

```
for (cont =0; cont<=SkelCargados.size();cont++) 
    if ( CantSkel[cont] == cual) break;
```

i think it should be:

```
for (cont =0; cont<SkelCargados.size();cont++) 
    if ( CantSkel[cont] == cual) break;
```

also make sure in

```
return SkelCargados[CantSkel[cont]];
```

that `cont` and `CantSkel[cont]` have valid values.

a tip: use `at()` instead of `[]` then you will get an `out_of_range` exception if the index is wrong, makes it easier to see..

Comment: Ok, I'm on it, thanks. However, that function doesn't crash anyway. Any thoughts about the second...?
Also thanks for the tip.